# could you tell me how to use the Executables evm？

Tags: evm

i use a contract as follows :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract TestContract
{
function multiply(uint a, uint b) returns (uint)
    {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

and `solc --bin-runtime TestContract.sol` to get its runtimecode.

then `evm --code 0x[runtimecode] --input 0x165c4a1600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007` run
(input value is got from Remix and solc --hashes xxx.sol ,input parameter 5,7)

but the result displayed in cmd is 0x .what's wrong?
if deploy in privatechain and execute the local method , it will return the correct answer 35.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contract code

```
contract TestContract
{
function multiply(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint)
    {
        return a*b;
    }
}
```

then

```
solc --bin-runtime TestContract.sol :

======= test.sol:TestContract =======
Binary of the runtime part: 
608060405260043610603f576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff168063165c4a16146044575b600080fd5b348015604f57600080fd5b5060766004803603810190808035906020019092919080359060200190929190505050608c565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b60008183029050929150505600a165627a7a72305820b321ef9f385622373dd6ff8a6ee31a7ead7dbccb991373435cef33b0526fd3110029
```

then call evm

```
evm --code 608060405260043610603f576000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff168063165c4a16146044575b600080fd5b348015604f57600080fd5b5060766004803603810190808035906020019092919080359060200190929190505050608c565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b60008183029050929150505600a165627a7a72305820b321ef9f385622373dd6ff8a6ee31a7ead7dbccb991373435cef33b0526fd3110029 --input 165c4a1600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000050000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007 run
```

your error was using calldata with 0x

the output result is

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000023
```

[image]